# right click (contextmenu) on div class, but not on a child div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to fire an event when right clicked on a div with class `types_list_button`, but within that div is another div with the class `hover_point` in which I do not want the event to fire when they are clicking over that div. Is this possible?

I am not sure if I can use `:not` with this type of event handler I am using.

**HTML**

```
<div class="types_list_button">Any where here<div class="hover_point">Not Here</div>Any where here</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.types_list_button', function() {
```

```js
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.types_list_button', function() {
  alert("test")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="types_list_button">Any where here<div class="hover_point">Not Here</div>Any where here</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for the class in the [`target` of the `Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) inside the event handler:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".types_list_button", function(evt) {
  if (!$(evt.target).hasClass("hover_point"))
    alert("test");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="types_list_button" style="margin:1em; padding:1em; background:#fcc;">Anywhere here
  <div class="hover_point" style="margin:1em; padding:1em; background:#cfc;">Not Here</div>
Anywhere here</div>
```

Comment: Happy to be of help :)

Comment: Unreal. +1 for clever.

Comment: it will fire the context menu if i click a second time

Comment: @dippas The green area is supposed to open the Context Menu.  The red area first shows an alert, and then opens the Context Menu.  The difference is in the alert, which should not fire in the green area.

Comment: Right, misunderstood that, the title say one thing, the question says other thing

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```js
$(document).on('contextmenu', '.types_list_button', function() {
  alert("test")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="types_list_button">
Any where here
</div>
<div class="hover_point">
Not Here
</div>
<div class="types_list_button">
Any where here
</div>
```

Comment: Cant change the HTML

Comment: It appears that, when there are two events present; that of the child inside that of the parent, the parent event always seems to prevail.

Comment: @Vini - check out Event Propagation in JavaScript, e.g. this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/968244